# Using bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

I have created the following code which does the bisection method. I am trying to use it to find the root for the function $f(x)=x^7-6x^6-28x^5+232x^4-336x^3-544x^2+1728x-1152$ on the interval $[1, 3.1]$ I have been given a hint that $x_0 = 2$ is a root for this function on the interval. Heres my code below: I am getting that there is no root, I was hoping someone could help me fix this! thanks

```
import math
import numpy as np
def root(x):
    return (x**7-6*x**6-28*x**5+232*x**4-336*x**3-544*x**2+1728*x-1152)

def bisection_method(f, a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        iter = 0
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0

            if f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint

            iter += 1
        return(midpoint, iter)

answer, iterations = bisection_method(root, 1, 3.1, 10**(-14))
print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
No root found.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ecdc56120415> in <module>()
 21         return(midpoint, iter)
 22 
---> 23 answer, iterations = bisection_method(root, 1, 3.1, 10**(-14))
 24 print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

Bisection doesn't work when you have even-multiplicity roots (because $f$ has the same sign either side), which is the case here.

$$f(x)=(x - 2)^4 (x + 2) (x - 6) (x + 6)$$

Your program falls in the first test `if f(a)*f(b)>0`: $f(1)=-105$ and $f(3.1)\approx -197$ so it immediately exit with no value returned.

By the way, `iter` is a [Python built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) returning an iterator object, so you shouldn't use it for a variable name.

Comment: okay so I guess I cant graph the error vs the number of iterations on this interval then? and I changed my iter variable name, thanks

Comment: If you want to use bisection, the first step should be to ensure you don't have repeated roots, e.g., for polynomials you can run Euclid on $f,f'$.

Answer (score 1):

For the comment on gcd of the polynomial and its derivative

The gcd turns out to be
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)    $$
Once you figure out that this is $(x-2)^3,$ you should check about $(x-2)^4$ dividing the original, which does happen.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{7}  - 6 x^{6}  - 28 x^{5}  + 232 x^{4}  - 336 x^{3}  - 544 x^{2}  + 1728 x  - 1152 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  7 x^{6}  - 36 x^{5}  - 140 x^{4}  + 928 x^{3}  - 1008 x^{2}  - 1088 x  + 1728 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{7}  - 6 x^{6}  - 28 x^{5}  + 232 x^{4}  - 336 x^{3}  - 544 x^{2}  + 1728 x  - 1152 \right)  =  \left(  7 x^{6}  - 36 x^{5}  - 140 x^{4}  + 928 x^{3}  - 1008 x^{2}  - 1088 x  + 1728 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  - 6 }{ 49 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 608 x^{5}  + 4032 x^{4}  - 3840 x^{3}  - 25088 x^{2}  + 66048 x  - 46080 }{ 49 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  7 x^{6}  - 36 x^{5}  - 140 x^{4}  + 928 x^{3}  - 1008 x^{2}  - 1088 x  + 1728 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 608 x^{5}  + 4032 x^{4}  - 3840 x^{3}  - 25088 x^{2}  + 66048 x  - 46080 }{ 49 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 6517 x  - 9702 }{ 11552 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 41552 x^{4}  + 206976 x^{3}  - 244608 x^{2}  - 175616 x  + 338688 }{ 361 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 608 x^{5}  + 4032 x^{4}  - 3840 x^{3}  - 25088 x^{2}  + 66048 x  - 46080 }{ 49 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 41552 x^{4}  + 206976 x^{3}  - 244608 x^{2}  - 175616 x  + 338688 }{ 361 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 727054 x  - 1199964 }{ 6744409 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 13307904 x^{3}  - 79847424 x^{2}  + 159694848 x  - 106463232 }{ 137641 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 41552 x^{4}  + 206976 x^{3}  - 244608 x^{2}  - 175616 x  + 338688 }{ 361 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 13307904 x^{3}  - 79847424 x^{2}  + 159694848 x  - 106463232 }{ 137641 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 357453677 x  - 364198086 }{ 300259584 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  - 6 }{ 49 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  - 6 }{ 49 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 6517 x  - 9702 }{ 11552 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 931 x^{2}  - 588 x  + 12740 }{ 11552 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 6517 x  - 9702 }{ 11552 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 727054 x  - 1199964 }{ 6744409 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 19133 x^{3}  + 19494 x^{2}  + 596372 x  - 701784 }{ 2202256 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 133931 x^{2}  + 21660 x  + 2531332 }{ 2202256 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 357453677 x  - 364198086 }{ 300259584 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 137641 x^{4}  - 5505640 x^{2}  + 19820304 }{ 13307904 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 963487 x^{3}  + 825846 x^{2}  - 25876508 x  - 29730456 }{ 13307904 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 40 x^{2}  + 144 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 371 x^{2}  + 60 x  + 7012 }{ 589824 }  \right)  -  \left(  7 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  - 188 x  - 216 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 53 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 1652 x  - 1944 }{ 589824 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{7}  - 6 x^{6}  - 28 x^{5}  + 232 x^{4}  - 336 x^{3}  - 544 x^{2}  + 1728 x  - 1152 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  - 40 x^{2}  + 144 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  7 x^{6}  - 36 x^{5}  - 140 x^{4}  + 928 x^{3}  - 1008 x^{2}  - 1088 x  + 1728 \right)  =  \left(  7 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  - 188 x  - 216 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{7}  - 6 x^{6}  - 28 x^{5}  + 232 x^{4}  - 336 x^{3}  - 544 x^{2}  + 1728 x  - 1152 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 371 x^{2}  + 60 x  + 7012 }{ 589824 }  \right)  -  \left(  7 x^{6}  - 36 x^{5}  - 140 x^{4}  + 928 x^{3}  - 1008 x^{2}  - 1088 x  + 1728 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 53 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 1652 x  - 1944 }{ 589824 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  $$